# Isolated storage remove method

Tags: windows-phone

When I try to clear all my isolated storage at the lauch of my app I get the error message:

> "No overload for method Remove takes 0 arguments"

The code that I use is:

```
mystore.remove();
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The methode you are using needs to have 1 argument if you are developing for Windows Phone OS 7.1, Windows Phone OS 7.0. You need to specify the key. See the [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.remove%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for an example.

Comment: Ok, so how can I clear all the Isolated Store? Shoul I remove every single voice separately?

Comment: @user3425660 Be creative, save all keys in a list named X that you load on each start an then remove your files or put all files in a folder named Y that you delete on each startup ;-) MSDN is your [friend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile(v=vs.95).aspx)!